# Fatal error while calling function in Php

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function for a shopping cart program which is as follows:

```
<?

    public function get_price($pid){
        $result=mysql_query("select price from products where serial=$pid");
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        return $row['price'];
    }


?>
```

Above code is stored in includes/db.php file and I am calling it as follows:

```
 <? include("includes/db.php"); ?>
  <table>
<tr><td>$ <?=get_price($pid)?></td></tr>
</table>
```

After running the script I am getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_price().I tried $this-> but that is not working.Can i get some guidance.

Comment: maybe you should define get_price() inside a class

Comment: That is because the `get_price()` function appears to be a class method, due to the `public` visibility keyword. If you look through the includes/db.php file, is the get_price function within a class? You will need to instantiate an object of that class in order to use that function.

Comment: I tried adding a class and creating object and shows me  Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price() on a non-object.

Comment: You know what else is a fatal error? Using `mysql_*`.

Answer (score 1):

If the function get_price($pid) is not inside a class...remove the public part, but if it belong to a class you have to create the object to before to call it..

Comment: how about this code snippet <?

 
  function get_price($pid){
  $result=mysql_query("select price from products where serial=$pid");
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  return $row['price'];

 ?>  <td>$ <?=get_price($pid)?></td>

Comment: Using shorthand tags is bad practice. Use `<?php`